# ionic unit testing - the pipe 'date' could not be found

Tags: angular, unit-testing, ionic-framework

I have a component that uses pipe date in template. It works in emulator and browser.

When executing unit tests - I get a

Error: The pipe 'date' could not be found!

For all test cases within that component.  Using latest ionic, angular, jasmine, karma, etc.

app.module.ts

```
import { CommonModule, DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
declarations: [AppComponent, DatePipe], 
imports: [ Common Module ],
providers: [CommonModule],
exports: [CommonModule]

...
```

users.page.spec.ts

```
import { CommonModule, DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
describe('UsersPage', () => {
  let component: UsersPage;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<UsersPage>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ CommonModule],
      declarations:[DatePipe],
      schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ],
      providers: [
        { provide: UserInfoService, useClass: MockUserInfoService },
        { provide: TaskHistoryService, useClass: MockTaskHistoryService },
        { provide: CommonModule, useClass: CommonModule}
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
    

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UsersPage);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

Error:

```
Error: The pipe 'date' could not be found!
    at getPipeDef$1 (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:24393:1)
    at ɵɵpipe (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:24356:1)
    at UsersPage_Template (ng:///UsersPage.js:115:9)
    at executeTemplate (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:7329:1)
    at renderView (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:7138:1)
    at renderComponent (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:8382:1)
    at renderChildComponents (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:6997:1)
    at renderView (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:7163:1)
    at ComponentFactory$1.create (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:22291:1)
    at initComponent (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/testing.js:1983:1)
```

I also have CommonModule inside of providers for @Component of the component using the date pipe. It feels like I'm missing something simple. I've read through similar questions (for custom pipes) and tried to apply same fixes - so far nothing worked. Thanks in advance.

Lastly, some version numbers:

```
Angular CLI: 10.0.3
Node: 14.5.0
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 10.0.4
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: <error>

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.1000.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.1000.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.1000.3
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.1000.3
@angular-devkit/core              10.0.3
@angular-devkit/schematics        10.0.3
@angular/cli                      10.0.3
@ngtools/webpack                  10.0.3
@schematics/angular               9.1.7
@schematics/update                0.1000.3
rxjs                              6.6.0
typescript                        3.9.7
webpack                           4.43.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Never mind. Does anyone else have an tendency where simply formulating the question allows them to answer it?
If you are reading this from the future, stuck with similar issue, read on:
My issue resolved itself when I declared the module under testing:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
 imports: [CommonModule],
 providers: [
        { provide: UserInfoService, useClass: MockUserInfoService },
        { provide: TaskHistoryService, useClass: MockTaskHistoryService },
      ],
 declarations:[UsersPage]
    }).compileComponents();
```

Now, a whole lot of errors showed up after that, but those were easy to resolve (mostly dealing with the fact that my MOC returned a null where my spec said should not be allowed. Sigh.

Finally feels like things are starting to click. Still, no guarantee that my thinking is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Pipe names are **case sensitive** and the date pipe is all lowercase.

Might require CommonModule which Exports all the basic Angular directives and pipes, such as NgIf, NgForOf, DecimalPipe, and so on. Re-exported by BrowserModule, which is included automatically in the root AppModule when you create a new app with the CLI new command.